# cascading dropdown boxes pulling from db

Tags: php, html, ajax

I'm trying to make two dropdown boxes that are populated from a db using php and ajax.  The first dropdown box only has one selection but when you select it, it should populate the second drop down box with different departments from my school being pulled from the database.  On selecting a department all the courses from that department should be displayed in a third drop down box.  Right now I'm just trying to get the dropdown box with all the departments to populate, it doesn't populate anything right now when you click it.  I think there's a problem with the loop to write the names of the departments in the drop down box.  Here's my code

index.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" 
            content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

            function getXMLHTTP() { //function to return the xml http object
                var xmlhttp=false;    
                try{
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                catch(e)    {        
                    try{            
                        xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    catch(e){
                        try{
                            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                        }
                        catch(e1){
                            xmlhttp=false;
                        }
                    }
                }

                return xmlhttp;
            }

            function getDept() {        

                var strURL="findDept.php";
                var req = getXMLHTTP();

                if (req) {

                    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (req.readyState == 4) {
                            // only if "OK"
                            if (req.status == 200) {                        
                                document.
                                    getElementById("deptdiv").
                                        innerHTML=req.responseText;
                            } else {
                                alert("There was a problem " +
                                    "while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                            }
                        }                
                    }            
                    req.open("GET", strURL, true);
                    req.send(null);
                }        
            }
            function getCourse(deptId) {        
            var strURL="findCourse.php?dept="+deptId;
            var req = getXMLHTTP();

            if (req) {
                req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (req.readyState == 4) {
                            // only if "OK"
                            if (req.status == 200) {                        
                                document.
                                    getElementById('coursediv').
                                        innerHTML=req.responseText;
                            } else {
                                alert("There was a problem " +
                                    "while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                            }
                        }                
                    }            
                    req.open("GET", strURL, true);
                    req.send(null);
                }
            } 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor= 'red' >
        <p>
            <font size="8" face="arial" 
                color="black">WELCOME TO SCHEDULE BUILDER</font>
        </p>
        <form method="post" action="" name="form1">
            <table width="60%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td width = "150">Semester</td>
                    <td width="150">
                        <select name="semester onChange="getDept()">
                            <option value="">Select Semester</option>
                            <option value ="1">Spring 2012</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>Department</td>
                    <td >
                        <div id="deptdiv">
                            <select name="department">
                                <option>Select Department</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>Course</td>
                    <td >
                        <div id="coursediv">
                            <select name="course">
                                <option>Select Department First</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

findDept.php

```
<?
    $link = mysql_connect("sql2.njit.edu", "sk442_proj", "jZ1MOA0X");
    if (!link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("sk442_proj");
    $query="SELECT abbrev FROM department";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
?>
<select name="department" onchange="getCourse(this.value)">
    <option>Select Department</option>
<? while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
    <option value=$row['abbrev']><?=$row['abbrev']?></option>
<? } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: you have a missing quotation mark in: <select name="semester[HERE] onChange="getDept()">

Answer (score 0):

This is a dynamic drop down I use maybe it will help:

main.php

```
include('pla2.php');
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#wait_1').hide();
    $('#drop_1').change(function(){
      $('#wait_1').show();
      $('#result_1').hide();
      $.get("pla2.php", {
        func: "drop_1",
        drop_var: $('#drop_1').val()
      }, function(response){
        $('#result_1').fadeOut();
        setTimeout("finishAjax('result_1', '"+escape(response)+"')", 400);
      });
        return false;
    });
});


function finishAjax(id, response) {
  $('#wait_1').hide();
  $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
  $('#'+id).fadeIn();
} 
</script>
<select name="drop_1" id="drop_1">

      <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select a Category</option>

      <?php getTierOne(); ?>

    </select> 

    <span id="wait_1" style="display: none;">
    <img alt="Please Wait" src="ajax-loader.gif"/>
    </span>
    <span id="result_1" style="display: none;"></span> 
    <span id="wait_2" style="display: none;">
    <img alt="Please Wait" src="ajax-loader.gif"/>
    </span>
    <span id="result_2" style="display: none;"></span>
```

pla2.php

```
function getTierOne()
{
    $catresult = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT category FROM categories") 
    or die(mysql_error());

      while($tier = mysql_fetch_array( $catresult )) 

        {
           echo '<option value="'.$tier['category'].'">'.$tier['category'].'</option>';
        }

}

//**************************************
//     First selection results     //
//**************************************
if($_GET['func'] == "drop_1" && isset($_GET['func'])) { 
   drop_1($_GET['drop_var']); 
}

function drop_1($drop_var)
{  
    include_once('db.php');
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT level1 FROM categories WHERE category='$drop_var'") 
    or die(mysql_error());

    echo '<select name="drop_2" id="drop_2">
          <option value=" " disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose one</option>';

           while($drop_2 = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
            {
              echo '<option value="'.$drop_2['level1'].'">'.$drop_2['level1'].'</option>';
            }

    echo '</select>';
```

Comment: The file findDept.php is getting called, and the connection to the database is working, but my database entries are still not being populated in the dropdown box, I think there is something wrong with my loop making the options of the dropdown box, I've used the code I put before as well as a variation of the answer, but it's still not working

Comment: Are you echoing out the option values. Look at the part of my code right after the while loop pay close attention to the type of quotes that are used as well.

Comment: Got first dropdown box populating, but having trouble with the second.  What does your code mean when you say if ($_GET['func'] == "drop_1" && isset($_GET['func'])

Comment: That has to do with a script that is on my index page I'll give it to you when I get back. It will store the value of the first drop down so you can use it

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#wait_1').hide();
 $('#drop_1').change(function(){
   $('#wait_1').show();
   $('#result_1').hide();
      $.get("pla2.php", {
  func: "drop_1",
  drop_var: $('#drop_1').val()
      }, function(response){
        $('#result_1').fadeOut();
        setTimeout("finishAjax('result_1', '"+escape(response)+"')", 400);
      });
     return false;
 });
});


function finishAjax(id, response) {
  $('#wait_1').hide();
  $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
  $('#'+id).fadeIn();
} </script

Answer (score 0):

this is how i use my dynamic select menu, i update the division in which the second menu is in, Category is the first menu, then brand the second

```
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('brand');
            ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
    }
    var category = document.getElementById('category').value;
    var queryString = "&category=" + category;
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "cat_to_brand_special.php?section=cat" + queryString, true);
    var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById("brand");
    ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = "<p style=\"padding-left:8px; font-size:11px; color:#DD0000\"><img style=\"border: 0px solid\" src='ajax-loader-form.gif'/> Loading...</p>"
    ajaxRequest.send(null);
```

the html part...

```
   <table><td>
       <div>
          <select id="category" name="category" onchange='ajaxFunction("special_cat")'>  <option value="000">--- Select Category ---</option><?php echo $menu_list?></select>
       </div>
   </td>
   <td>
       <div id="brand">
           <select id='brands' name="brands"><option value="000">--- Select Brand ---</option><?php echo $menu_list_2; ?></select>
       </div>
   </td><table>
```

the php part that will be outputed

```
    $cat=$_GET['category'];
    $display="<select name=\"brand\">";
    $result=mysql_query("select name from brands where category = '$cat'")
    while($db_fields=mysql_fetch_assoc($result){
        $name=$db_fields['name'];
        $display .= "<option>$name</option>";
    }
    $display .="</select>";
    echo $display;
```

just an example you can use...